# In this sentence (let's get started). The ( 's) is shortcut for what?

Tags: causative-get

I need help to explain the shortcut ('s) that follows the word let in the sentence (let's get started).
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for joining ELL, and welcome! We hope you'll have more to contribute and to learn. To ask useful questions, please spend some time reading [How do I ask a good question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

In English, *let's* is a *contraction* of the first person plural present tense of the verb *let,* and the first person plural pronoun *us.* The "apostrophe s" represents *us*. The phrase is in the *imperative mood,* and the expanded construction is *let us*.